# Assigning unique names to each square in a game map

Tags: python, oop, pygame

I'm making a game that involves a map of square tiles (like Civ III). Each square in the map is an object with x,y coordinates and some other attributes (resources on the tile, elevation, etc).

My map file is stored as an array, like so:

```
tilemap =   [
        [GRASS, DIRT, DIRT],
        [GRASS, GRASS, WATER],
        [GRASS, GRASS, WATER],
        [DIRT, GRASS, WATER],
        [DIRT,  GRASS, GRASS]
        ]
```

I want to go through the map and make a square at the x,y coordinates given by the location in the array, and with the type indicated by the text (grass, dirt, etc).

So far, I've tried this:

```
class LevelMap():
def __init__(self, level_array=tilemap):
    self.level_array = level_array

    # Go through every row in the map...
    for row in range(MAPHEIGHT):
        # ... and every column...
        for column in range(MAPWIDTH):
            # ...and make a square at that location.
            Square(row, column, tilemap[row][column])
```

The Square class takes the arguments `Square(x,y,square_type)`.

However, I do not know how to give each square its own unique name, so I can say

```
square_1 = the square at 0,0
square_2 = the square at 0,1
```

and so on, so that I can use e.g. square1.get_square_type() or square_1.change_terrain_type(rocky).

How can I turn my map array into a group of Square objects with unique names?

I'm using Python 3.4 and pygame.

Comment: Your "unique ID" would be `x+y*MAPWIDTH`

Comment: @Draco18s How can I use that ID to reference on object in a method call? I get that x+y*MAPWIDTH will be unique for every square, but I need something I can use to say square_1.square_type.

I can't do (x+y*MAPWIDTH).square_type.

Perhaps 'name' would be a better term to use, rather than 'ID?'

Comment: `y = (int)(val / MAPWIDTH)` `x = (int)(val % MAPWIDTH)` provided that the syntax matches python (I have not worked in python, but I assume it has the modulo operator `%` and some method of casting to an integer).

Comment: @Draco18s Okay, I think you're answering a different question than the one that I have. I'll try editing my question to make it more clear. Thanks, though!

Comment: Do you mean you want a variable in your code called `square_1`?  You can't do that for an arbitrarily sized array.  This is what *collections* (arrays, lists, dictionaries, etc) are for.  You would want to store the `Square` objects in an array as well.  Look up how to declare a two dimensional empty array.

Comment: @Dracos18s Okay, I think I'm getting it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You don't.

You said already that you have your map stored as a 2D list. You only reference your tiles by their index in that array.

```
class LevelMap():
    def __init__(self, level_array=tilemap):
        self.level_array = level_array
    
        # Go through every row in the map...
        for row in range(MAPHEIGHT):
            # ... and every column...
            for column in range(MAPWIDTH):
                # ...and make a square at that location.
                Square(row, column, tilemap[row][column])

map = LevelMap(level_array=[])
# change the tile at (0, 1) to rocky:
map.level_array[1][0].change_terrain_to("rocky")
```

I'd even strongly recommend writing a helper function onto `LevelMap` that gets a tile given its `(x,y)`.

```
class LevelMap():
    ...
    def get_tile(self, x, y):
        return self.level_array[y][x]

map = LevelMap()
tile = map.get_tile(0, 1)
# or
location = (0, 1)
tile = map.get_tile(*location)
```

When I've written things like this in the past, I've made my `Map` a child of `list`

```
class Map(list):
    def __init__(self, height, width):
        for y in range(height):
            self.append([Square(y, x, tilemap[y][x]) for x in range(width)])
    def get_tile(self, x, y):
        return self[y][x]
```

Comment: Now things make sense! Thanks!